# iPhone Accelerometer in Background

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer

I am creating an app which checks car's speed continuously. Is it possible to check speed using accelerometer in Background ?

Comment: You can certainly get accelerometer data, but I would think that it would be inefficient to try and calculate the speed using it. Have you considered using CoreLocation to calculate the speed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use core location and Yes you can use core location in background mode.

Just remember to switch on location updates in target -> capabilities -> background modes.

There is easy to find some tutorials online how to works with core location.